# DV01 of 10-Year vs 1-Year Zero-Coupon Bond at 0% Flat Interest Rate Curve

Tags: fixed-income, yield, term-structure, dv01

As the title suggests, what are the DV01s of a 1 million principal zero-coupon bond with 10-year and 1-year TTM with an assumed 0% flat interest rate curve. I understand that the duration for both bonds is just their TTM because all the principal is received at maturity (definition of duration). However, should the current price of the bond be same as the principal because of the 0% flat interest rate curve?

If the previous assumption is correct, this would lead me to a DV01 of the zero-coupon bonds using the formula:

$DV01_{10Y} = Duration * Principal * \frac{\Delta r}{(1+r)^{10}} = 10 * 1mil * \frac{0.0001}{(1+0)^{10}}$

$DV01_{1Y} = Duration * Principal*\frac{\Delta r}{1+r} = 1 * 1mil * \frac{0.0001}{1+0}$

And therefore the DV01 of the 10-year is 10 times that of the 1-year? Honestly, it does make sense to me, but I am just a bit suspicious of the price of the zero-coupon bond being the same as the principal, because it is usually the yield that is being used to discount and not the riskless rate.

PS. If this is too simple, please feel free to vote to close.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. If the interest rates and yields are 0, then yes, present value = future value. If we define the present value of a zero-coupon bond maturing in $t$ years, with quoted annual yield $y$, as p.v. $=$ future value $\times (1+y)^{-t}$, We have such bonds, maturing in 1 year and in $n$ years, both yielding 0 in the base scenario, and hence priced at 100% of the face value, are you asking _why_  the ratio of the change of the present values in a risk scenario increasing both yields from 0 by the same small amount $\delta$ is close to the

Comment: to the maturity $n$? I.e. the algebra explaining why $\frac{100\% \times (1+\delta)^{-n} - 100\%}{100\% \times (1+\delta)^{-1} - 100\%}  \approx n $.

Comment: Hi @DimitriVulis, thanks for giving me your opinion on this. Yes, your interpretation of the question is correct. Btw, where did you get your formula? I assume the $\delta$ is the 1bp change in yield. Also, an additional question I am asking is why is the riskless rate being used to discount the FV of the ZC bond, when usually YTM of bonds are used to determine the market price of bonds instead.

Comment: The formula is just (present value of the n-year zero-coupon bond when its 0 yield is bumped by $\delta$, such as 1 basis point, - p.v.  when yield is 0)/(p.v. of the 1-year bond when its 0 yield is bumped by $\delta$ - p.v.  when yield is 0).

Comment: Thanks, but should the DV01 is the same? I would have expected the duration to enter the equation.

Comment: If the binds so high-yield/distressed that their market price materially depends on the assumption of the recovery after default, then their sensitivity to interest rates is less than the yield01. Is that it01 what you mean by dv01?